# jQuery button click, get div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a client script in jQuery and I'm trying to make it as generic as possible.

I'm looking for a way to select a div with the class ".targets" from a button click.

My markup looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <!-- Products section -->
    <div class="products">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="targets">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Resources section, slightly different markup -->
    <div class="resources">
        <div class="container">
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn-add">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="targets">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$("form").on("click", "btn-add", function(e){
   var targets = $(this).parent().parent().next();
});
```

This solution works "somehow", but what if the markup changes?

Is there a way in jQuery to select the closest div with the class ".targets" on button click?

Thanks :)

Comment: `$(this).closest('.containers').find('.targets')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(this).closest(".container").find(".targets");`

this will select the closest element with the class `container` and search for an element in that with the class `targets`

```js
$("form").on("click", ".btn-add", function(e){
   var targets = $(this).closest(".container").find(".targets");
   console.log($(targets).text().trim())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <!-- Products section -->
    <div class="products">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="targets">
                target1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Resources section, slightly different markup -->
    <div class="resources">
        <div class="container">
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn-add">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="targets">
                target2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know they will always be within the `.products` element, you could do:

```
$(this).closest('.products').find('.targets');
```

A helpful guide for jQuery traversing methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Would this not only work for the first button? since the second button dont have a parent called `products`

Comment: It would, but the point is to find the closest element that will always be present, no matter what the mark-up will be changed to. I avoided using the `.container` because in my experience you find that with modern coding techniques, "containers" or "wrappers" aren't needed, and then you end up removing them ;)

Comment: If you look at his html, 1 button is inside "products", and one inside "resources". So if he use your code, nothing will happen when i clicks the second button

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) which searches for selector higher up in tree and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) which searches for selector going down the tree

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.targets')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.targets')
```

Comment: I dont need copy :)